# How to specify a specific value for an auto increment column in SQL Server?

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have an auto increment identity column in sql server, but I want to specify a specific value for one of the rows.  So the number scheme would be as follows:

```
1 ...,
2....,
999 - for the reserved entry,
3....,
n....
```

How can I do this?

Comment: As a side note, you'd need to be careful when you insert row 998; as the next insert will violate the PK constraint (since 999 is already in there)

Comment: Thanks Jim B, the assumption is that this table is sufficiently small enough that it will never reach the reserved number.

Comment: No problem.  We had something similar like this here; where we decided that 1-499 would be reserved, so the identity seed started at 500.  not sure if that'll help in your scenario.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You need to use `IDENTITY_INSERT`:

```
SET IDENTITY_INSERT MyTableName ON

INSERT INTO MyTableName
(IdField, <list of all the fields>)
VALUES
(999, <list of other values)

SET IDENTITY_INSERT MyTableName OFF

DBCC CHECKIDENT(MyTableName, RESEED, 2)
```

You also have to use the explicit field list in the `INSERT` statement, and are limited to one active `IDENTITY_INSERT` per session.

This will also reset the seed value to be whatever you inserted if it's higher than the current ID value.

You can get around this too by using [`DBCC CHECKIDENT`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms176057.aspx) but it'll be a big pain to manage.

Comment: Thanks JNK, I added the DBCC call to your answer.

Answer (score 6):

You can use [IDENTITY_INSERT](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms188059.aspx):

```
SET IDENTITY_INSERT [tablename] ON;
INSERT INTO [tablename] (identitycolumn, ... ) VALUES (999, ...);
SET IDENTITY_INSERT [tablename] OFF;
```

Having to resort to this is always a code smell. It is onyl acceptable as a data load practice for table population, or for replicating data. For an app to 'reserve' IDs is a a bad practice and indicates a data model design flaw.

Comment: Remu are you the service broker guru from rusanu consulting? If you are your dialog pooling techniques really opened my eyes to the power of service broker.