# How do I use Linqpad to insert record with specified primary key?

Tags: c#, entity-framework, linqpad

So when I run the following, the role is inserted but the ID column is auto generated. How do I stop this from happening when using Linqpad?

```
Roles.InsertOnSubmit(new Role(){ID = 26, Name = "TheRole", Created = DateTime.Now, Updated = DateTime.Now});    
SubmitChanges();
```

Comment: I was looking for the function name, got from your question. Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The ID column is set to AUTO INCREMENT in database, you can't override that from LINQ, you have to modify your database table schema to remove AUTO INCREMENT from table.

You can also enable `IDENTITY_INSERT` if you are using ADO.Net, see [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10214297/how-to-specify-a-specific-value-for-an-auto-increment-column-in-sql-server) for related SQL details.